# CSS content with delay

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS `content` property to add content before an html tag.

```css
span::before {
    content: 'content that needs a delay';
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Is there a way to delay the visibility of the content (with CSS)?

Comment: i don't think you can do it with CSS. you can use jquery function "show" for this. http://api.jquery.com/show/ see here

Comment: @AksheyBhat You can't use JS on pseudo-elements as they aren't in the DOM.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```css
span::before {
    content: 'content that needs a delay';
     margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    animation: fadein 4s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `css-animation`

```css
span::before {
  content: 'content that needs a delay';
  opacity: 0;
  animation: 2s fadeIn;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition: opacity 1.5s;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Comment: According to MDN, visibility property is animateable, but it animates as single step from invisible to visible

Comment: ikr. just wanted to highlight the importance of using the css animation for his desired effect. using opacity will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CSS animation` with css `animation-fill-mode:forwards` or else after completion of animation it will hide your content.

```css
span::before {
    content: 'content that needs a delay';
    -webkit-animation:0.6s opc forwards;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes opc{
 from{
   opacity:0;
 }
 to{
   opacity:1;
 }
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Comment: You also may animate `max-width` from 0 to something big with `overflow: hidden`, or `transform: translateX` from something big to 0, or whatever

Comment: @DenisSheremet that's true there are many such options that we can use, but while setting it's opacity to 0 we are not hiding that element instead we are just reducing it's opacity. Whereas if you hide a element and you have some element nearby, so the nearby element takes your place and on load i.e. while executing animation you can see that nearby element moves to right, try you will get my point :-)